How to control lightweight pull-up and pull-downs from GPIO-style pins?
I'm a novice at fine electrical theory.
My daughter and I have a few micro:bit cards, and we're starting to branch out from basic servo robotics. One such project is controlling her train layout. We already have control of a PWM motor controller and now we want to control a few house and street lights around the layout. Unfortunately these run at a couple of voltages, and both circuits run at a higher amperage than the micro:bit can kick out of its pins.
I have a pile of generic buck convertor boards that can get the voltage to the right level, but we'd like to be able to control them programmatically from the micro:bit. The convertors have an "enable" pin which is high by default, that can be pulled down to disable the power supply.
Given a 3.3v high from a micro:bit pin, how can I pull the buck convertor's enable pin down? Is this a transistor job, or a relay, or what? I don't really appreciate the limits of these switching devices, or know how to size them.
We may —in time— want to add per-house lighting control, leaving the power on, and doing similar switching to above, but the other way around. A house is about 60mA. Again, is this a job for a transistor or something heavier?

If the buck enable pin is 3v3 pull down directly with microbit pin. If more pull down with transistor.

Oh, you think I could just connect it to a pin and write high/low to turn it on and off?

@Oli You could but you would need to know what input levels the random pile of random regulators work with. They either work with 3.3V levels or not. You need to know what chips the modules have, and how the modules connect the enable pin before giving access to you.

There are no markings on the image of the board.
If the actual chips are marked AGCx (where x could be anything) then they are probably MP2315 chips, in which case you can try connecting 100kΩ in series with the EN input and controlling it directly with the 3.3V signal.
With the 100kΩ series resistor, nothing will be damaged if this guess is wrong.

Enable/SYNC control
EN is a digital control pin that turns the regulator on and off. Drive EN high to turn on the regulator, drive it
low to turn it off. There is an internal 1MEG resistor from EN to GND
thus EN can be floated to shut down the chip. Also EN pin voltage was
clamped to around 6.5V by an internal zener-diode. Please use large
enough pull up resistor connecting between VIN and EN to limit the EN
input current which should be less than 100uA. Generally, around 100k
resistor should be large enough for all the applications.

